# Please tell me how to detect ,UIScrollView using a single, double, two-finger taps

Tags: uiscrollview

Please tell me how to distinguish,single tap, double tap, two finger tapping on UIScrollview.
OS2.0 and OS3.0 must be the same motion。

Answer (score 1):

Look at the iPhone SDK example TapToZoom, which is contained within the 'ScrollViewSuite' sample code. [Link to SDK example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `UIGestureRecognizer` to the `UIScrollView`. Just use `UITapGestureRecognizer` is ok for your need. Like this:

```
//I assume you have alloc and initialized three UITapGestureRecognizer called singleTap, doubleTap, doubleFingerTap
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTap];
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleFingerTap];
```

Basically, `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` will make sure that if you double tap the view, the program won't recognize the first tap and then take action according to the first tap. It will wait for a little bit long time for the double tap to happen, if the user doesn't tap the second time, the program execute the function triggered by the singleTap. So using this function will cause a small lag in the program, as I noticed, it less than 0.5second.

Hope this may help.